# Как найти букву в верхнем регистре в строке?

Tags: delphi, строки

Есть строка, где нет пробелов, например: `ИвановПетрСидорович`

Надо найти позиции букв в верхнем регистре, чтобы отделить слова.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код решения я скорее всего не приведу, так как давно не практиковал Delphi...

Но общий ход алгоритма такой:

Перебираешь посильно строку.

Затем на каждой итерации цикла анализируешь букву на регистр. Не помню, есть ли специальная функция в Delphi для этого. Если есть, то используешь эту функцию, а если нет, то пишешь свою.

Если посмотреть таблицу ASCII , то можно увидеть, что большие буквы находятся в одном кодовом диапазоне, а мельнькие в другом.

**UPD**

В комментарии подсказывают, что есть спец. функции

> myStr[i], AnsiUpperCase (сравниваем myStr[i] c
>   AnsiUpperCase(myStr[i])), Copy, Delete (последнее - может и не
>   использоваться, зависит от реализации). В последних версиях Delphi
>   можно использовать и другие функции, но эти есть в любой версии.

Comment: Тогда уж дополните: myStr[i], AnsiUpperCase (сравниваем myStr[i] c AnsiUpperCase(myStr[i])), Copy, Delete (последнее - может и не использоваться, зависит от реализации). В последних версиях Delphi можно использовать и другие функции, но эти есть в любой версии.

Answer (score 4):

Есть несколько способов детектирования заглавной буквы в строке. Но они сильно зависят от того, какой версией Delphi вы пользуетесь и нужна ли вам поддержка юникода.

В современных версиях Delphi просто используйте функцию [TCharacter.IsUpper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Character.TCharacter.IsUpper) из юнита `Character`:

```
uses
  System.Character;

...

function SplitByUpper(const AStr: string): string;
var
  I: Integer;      
begin
  Result := '';      
  for I := 1 to Length(AStr) do begin
    if TCharacter.IsUpper(AStr[I]) and (Result <> '') then begin
      Result := Result + ' ';
    end;
    Result := Result + AStr[I];
  end;
end;
```

*Код носит иллюстративный характер и может быть оптимизирован!*

В старых Delphi можно использовать функцию [IsCharUpper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647485(v=VS.85).aspx) (работает с текущей локалью пользователя) из `WinApi` или генерировать список c информацией о каждом символе для конкретной локали самостоятельно, при помощи [GetStringTypeEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318118(v=vs.85).aspx). Генерирование списка будет оправдано, если вам нужно очень интенсивно использовать эту функцию и вы упираетесь в быстродействие.

Если нужен переносимый код между разными версиями Delphi, то можно взять JCL, там есть такая функция:

```
function CharIsUpper(const C: Char): Boolean;
begin
  {$IFDEF UNICODE_RTL_DATABASE}
  Result := TCharacter.IsUpper(C);
  {$ELSE ~UNICODE_RTL_DATABASE}
  Result := (StrCharTypes[C] and C1_UPPER) <> 0;
  {$ENDIF ~UNICODE_RTL_DATABASE}
end;
```

---

Этот же вопрос в английской версии SO: [How to detect if a character from a string is upper or lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8394326/6219657)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
const 
  UpperChars = 'АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЪЫЭЮЯ';'  
var
  Idx : integer;
begin
  ResStr := '';  
  for i := 1 to length(InStr) do
    begin
      Idx := Pos(InStr[i]), UpperChars); // узнаем верхний ли регистр у символа
      if (Idx > 0) and (i > 1) then // значит нужно вставить пробел
        ResStr := ResStr + ' ';
      ResStr := ResStr + InStr[i] // добавляем символ
    end;
```

ЗЫ Ну вы и намудрили...